# MSIE 9: Replace the yellow download bar at the bottom by the normal popup

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-9, watin

Is there some setting in MSIE, in the registry or some plugin/add-on that will let me get rid of the yellow download bar that pops up at the bottom of the window when I try to download something (with alternatives open, save, cancel and save-as), and instead have the MSIE-8 style popup dialog?

This yellow bar makes it difficult to test a site using Watin. And actually I am currently not able to test downloading at all because of this yellow bar. In MSIE 8 it worked as expected since there was the normal popup dialog window.

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Internet-Explorer-Information-bar-frequently-asked-questions

Check the **Can I turn off the Information bar** tab